# Having trouble implementing a copy constructor for a doubly linked list

Tags: c++, linked-list, copy-constructor

I am struggling to implement a copy constructor for a doubly linked list. The program compiles but I am running into an issue using the "push_back" function within the copy constructor to add the newly created nodes to the list. Below are the copy constructor and push_back functions in question.

```
List::List(const List& rhs) // Copy constructor
{
    //this pointer is for the list that is being copied from
    Node* rhsNodePtr;

    //setting the new pointer to the first node of the old list
    rhsNodePtr = rhs.first;

    //looping until the end of the list
    while(rhsNodePtr != nullptr){

        //declaring new node to copy data into
        Node* newNode = new Node("");

        //copying node data from original list into new node
        newNode->data = rhsNodePtr->data;

        //adding new copied node to a new list
        push_back(newNode->data);

        //advancing the old list pointer location for the loop
        rhsNodePtr = rhsNodePtr->next;
    }
}

void List::push_back(string element)
{ 
   Node* new_node = new Node(element);
   if (last == nullptr) // List is empty
   {  
      first = new_node;
      last = new_node;
   }
   else
   {  
      new_node->previous = last;
      last->next = new_node;
      last = new_node;
   }
}
```

I apologize if I have omitted any relevant details. Please note that I am not just looking for a solution or correction but an explanation of why the push_back(); function is not working in my current implementation.

Edit: The while loop in the copy constructor gets stuck after the push_back function is called.

Edit: "First" and "last" are initialized in the List class declaration and both set to "nullptr" in the constructor.

Edit: After running through a debugger, I learned that there is an illegal memory access(segmentation fault) that occurs in the push_back function in the line`last->next = new_node;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your copy constructor is not initializing `first` and `last` (unless you are doing so in the class declaration, which you did not show), and it also leaks a `Node` on each loop iteration.

Try this instead:

```
List::List(const List& rhs)
    : first(nullptr), last(nullptr) // <-- add this if needed
{
    Node* rhsNodePtr = rhs.first;
    while (rhsNodePtr) {
        push_back(rhsNodePtr->data); // <-- no need to allocate a new Node for this call
        rhsNodePtr = rhsNodePtr->next;
    }
}

void List::push_back(string element)
{ 
   Node* new_node = new Node(element);
   new_node->previous = last;
   new_node->next = nullptr; // <-- add this if needed
   if (!first) first = new_node;
   if (last) last->next = new_node;
   last = new_node;
}
```

Comment: Updated my code to reflect the changes you made. After running it through a debugger, there appears to be an illegal memory access in the line ```if(last) last->next = new_node;``` Which also happens with my original push_back implementation.

Comment: That would imply that your other `List` methods are not managing `last` correctly, causing it to point to an invalid `Node`. Or, if you are calling `push_back()` on an invalid `List` object. Use your debugger to verify.

Comment: After reading your suggestion, I commented out my "erase" function and the program ran without issue so there must be some problem with that function. Thank you.

Comment: You likely forgot to update `last`, or are doing so incorrectly, when removing a `Node` from the end of the `List`.

Answer (score 3):

You are not initializing `last` in the copy constructor. So the push_back gets called with garbage in it.

BTW I don't see the need for `newNode` and you don't free it. You can just `push_back(rhsNodePtr->data);` directly.